# Show that 1 and -1 are the only eigenvalues of this linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Define $T: M_{n\times n}\to M_{n\times n}$ by $T(A):= A^t$. Note that $T$ is a linear transformation.

Show that $1$ and $-1$ are the only eigenvalues of $T$.

> Let $\lambda$ denote an eigenvalue of $T$. Then $T(A) = \lambda A = A^t$. We know that if $A$ is a symmetric matrix, then $A = A^t$ and if $A$ is a skew symmetric matrix then $-A = A^t$, ie. the only eigenvalues of $T$ are $1$ and $-1$ for the cases where $A$ is symmetric and skew symmetric.

Do I need to show these are the only possible times that $\lambda A$ can equal $A^t$? If so, how can I show that there are no other cases?

Comment: Raising a matrix to a power is *not* a linear transformation.  Does $(A+B)^t = A^t + B^t$?  Does $(cA)^t = c(A^t)$ ?

Comment: @DanielV It means transpose.

Comment: Hint: In general if $L : V\to V$ is linear and $L^2 = id$, what is the possible choice of eigenvalues?

Comment: @DanielV, no mention of powers in this problem, only transpose and eigenvalues.

Comment: @John, hey, this is a serious question (it may seem sarcastic, but why do people always edit questions? It doesn't really change anything as to how it is viewed, so why the need? (Sorry, I'm new to the site and still trying to understand it.

Comment: @Ian Thanks.  I've never seen lower cased $t$ used like that, but the one thing all linear algebra authors have in common is that they all like to come up with new notations.

Comment: @Chad : It does change something. Take a look at the second line in the question, where +1 and -1 are not put into the dollar sign. So it looks different to other $\pm 1$.

Answer (score 12):

if $\lambda$ is an eigen value and the corresponding eigenvector is $A \neq 0,$  then $$A^\top = \lambda A $$ taking transpose gives you $$A = \lambda A^\top=\lambda^2 A $$ which show you $$\lambda^2 = 1\implies \lambda = \pm 1. $$

Comment: Genius! Thanks!

Comment: This answer is really useful...

Answer (score 3):

Note that $T^2$ is an identity transformation, so the minimal polynomial of $T$ is $\lambda^2-1.$

More generally, given a linear transformation $L$ such that there is a least positive integer $k$ for which $L^k$ is an identity transformation, we will always have that the minimal polynomial of $L$ *divides* $\lambda^k-1.$ (We may, in fact, have equality, but I'm not certain of that.)

Comment: how can I conclude that because $T^2$ is the id transformation, the characteristic equation is $\lambda^2 = 1$?

Comment: Because the identity transformation has $1$ as its only eigenvalue, and for any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $T,$ we have that $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $T^2:=T\circ T.$

Comment: $T$ is a linear operator on an $n^2$-dimensional space: its *characteristic* polynomial has degree $n^2$; in fact, it is $(x - 1)^{n(n+1)/2} (x + 1)^{n(n-1)/2}$. Your approach is fine, of course; you just have the wrong description.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Good grief.... Thank you for bringing that to my attention.

Comment: @Chad: Apologies for the confusion. I was misusing my terminology rather badly.